# Any way to incorporate two different fonts in a heading (e.g., <h1>, <h2>, etc.)?

Tags: html-heading

So, on my blog, I am often using both English words and Hebrew, Arabic, and Greek words in headings. I would like the English words to be a particular font (e.g., Calibri), and the Hebrew words to be a particular font (e.g., SBL Hebrew), and the Arabic words to be a particular font (e.g., Traditional Arabic)...and so on.

Is there any way to accomplish this?

This is currently my HTML code for the h1 heading:

```
h1.entry-title,
h1.archive-title {
    color: #333;
    font-family: Hebrew, "SBL Hebrew", "Times New Roman", serif;
    font-size: 2.2em;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: 200;
    line-height: 1.25em;
    margin: 1em 0 0.4em 0;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: I should add, I'm using WordPress software on my personal website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Font-Family fallback**

The most basic way is too create [font-family](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-family) fallback. This will work only with per-language fonts (SBL Hebrew can't render arabic or english, Rraditional Arabic can't render English, etc.)

```
font-family: "SBL Hebrew", "Traditional Arabic", Calibri;
```

And a working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/cWzwT/

---

**lang attribute**

You can also try the following method showed in this post - [Internationalization Language CSS](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/internationalization-language-css/) :

```
:lang(he) { font-family: "SBL Hebrew" }
:lang(ar) { font-family: "Traditional Arabic" }
```

Using the [:lang](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:lang) method shown here is compatible with most modern browsers so it should do the trick. It probably requires to add a `lang` attribute to the element, so I don't know if that exactly fits your problem.

---

**unicode-range**

Another more general way is using the [unicode-range](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-fonts/#unicode-range-desc). For example

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "SBL Hebrew";
    unicode-range: U+05-90, U+05-FF;
}
```

For further reading:

- [Creating Custom Font Stacks with Unicode-Range](http://24ways.org/2011/creating-custom-font-stacks-with-unicode-range/).
- [Can CSS choose a different default font and size depending on Language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/535616/can-css-choose-a-different-default-font-and-size-depending-on-language)
- [Here](http://jrgraphix.net/research/unicode_blocks.php)'s a table with the unicode ranges.

Comment: Sounds good. Will do more research on that. I appreciate the link.

Comment: @H3br3wHamm3r81 : Notice there are two links in my post. I think it requires to give the element a `lang` attribute.

Comment: Yes, sir. I'm reading up. This should do the trick. At the least, you've given me a direction to go. Thanks again.