# Why a replacement of fonts changes not only English characters, but also Chinese characters?

Tags: css, fonts

Originally my website uses two Google fonts, i.e., Montserrat and Lato. To reduce the load time for these fonts, I replace them with web safe fonts Georgia and Arial.

It is obviously that the English texts in the websites are changed.

However, I notice that the Chinese texts are also changed.

So I go back to Google fonts and check if their fonts have Chinese subset:

https://fonts.google.com/?query=Montserrat&subset=chinese-simplified
https://fonts.google.com/?query=Lato&subset=chinese-simplified

All returns empty.

So, how can know what will they be in Chinese characters?

And why the replacement of the fonts will also change the Chinese characters?

BTW: I find the way to specify the font for different languages: [Can CSS choose a different default font and size depending on Language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/535616/can-css-choose-a-different-default-font-and-size-depending-on-language)

**Update:**

1. The original font family(for headings and menu items):

```
font-family: Montserrat;
```

replaced with:

```
font-family: 'Georgia', 'Verdana', 'Arial', serif, sans-serif;
```

2. The original font family(for paragraph texts):

```
font-family: Lato;
```

replaced with:

```
font-family: 'Arial', 'Helvetica', 'Tahoma', 'Times New Roman', sans-serif, serif;
```

Comment: Could you include precisely the values you had and now have for the `font-family` property?

Comment: And I'm not clear if it's really part of your question, but to see if a given FontFace will be used to render a text, you can do `await document.fonts.load("10px Montserrat", the_text)`. If this returns an empty Array, an other substitution font will be used (and if it does return an Array with the FontFace in it, you may be able to inspect its `unicodeRange` values.

Comment: @Kaiido, Just do that in the update, thank you very much!

Comment: So the fallback Chinese font changed because of "serif, sans-serif" or "sans-serif, serif". Your system probably has two different fonts registered for Chinese glyphs, at least one serif and one sans. The default might have been "sans-serif" before, but now that you do say it to fallback on "serif" first, it will use the other serif  font with these glyphs. If you want the previous default font, remove these keywords. And if I may, it sounds a bit weird to fallback Georgia with Verdana and Arial, which are two sans-serif fonts.

Comment: @Kaiido, Sorry but the original font-family does not provide a fallback font at all. It only uses Montserrat and Lato. The replacements uses fallback fonts and generic font-familry such as serif and sans-serif.

Comment: There is **always** a system font fallback. (even the square glyphs you may see when no installed font support a glyph is actually a system font). Which will be used between "serif" "sans-serif", "cursive" etc. will depend on the element where the text is drawn, and it can generally be set as a user-preference in the browser's settings, the default is generally sans-serif.

Comment: @Kaiido, OK. I see. Thank you very much.