# Replacing innerText with an innerHTML - [object HTMLSpanElement] error

Tags: javascript, jquery, styles, character

Solved:

I receive Chinese content from an API and use a special font for this language. But some names in this content have a-zA-Z0-9 letters and for them I want to use "Montserrat" font. Now I write a span around these words / numbers:

```
打扰一下。打扰一下。[object HTMLSpanElement] [object HTMLSpanElement] 打扰一下。打扰一下。
```

This is what I want:

```
<div class="vce-post-description--excerpt">
<p>打扰一下。打扰一下。<span style="font-family: Montserrat;">51612</span> <span style="font-family: Montserrat;">Hello</span> 打扰一下。打扰一下。</p>
</div>
```

Here the solution - JS part:

```
<script>
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {

    const regex = /[0-9A-Za-z]+/g;
  
    var textElements = document.querySelectorAll(".vce-post-description--title a, .vce-post-description--excerpt");
  
  
    for (var i = 0; i < textElements.length; i++) {
   
        if (textElements[i].textContent.match(regex)) {
       
            var foundString = textElements[i].textContent.match(regex).toString();
      //console.log("Changing Words: "+foundString);
      let foundArray = foundString.split(",");
      foundArray.forEach(changeInnerText);

        }
    }

    
  function changeInnerText(item) {
        addElement = document.createElement('span');
        addElement.style.fontFamily = "Montserrat";
        addElement.style.visibility = "visible";
        addElement.textContent  = item;
        //console.log('New Style: '+addElement.outerHTML);
        var regex = new RegExp(item, "g");
                tempHTML = textElements[i].innerHTML.replace(regex, addElement.outerHTML);
        textElements[i].innerHTML = tempHTML;
  }
  
})

</script>
```

And here is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/knutbecker/rjgu02fq/67/).

Comment: Simply set your alternative font: `font-family: "Some Custom Chinese Font", Arial, sans-serif;` - when a character variant is missing it's taken from the alternative fonts. If the Custom Font has those code points taken, simply enter a font editor and remove them. Save the font file and clear the cache before re-using it. Or use a [Unicode Range](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face/unicode-range)

Comment: Also [have a look at css3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/535616/can-css-choose-a-different-default-font-and-size-depending-on-language)

Comment: Thank you @RokoC.Buljan , but A-Z characters exist in the Chinese font, but it's quiet ugly to read so that I have to change it.

Comment: Thank you too, @mplungjan , but I receive the Chinese content via API and give it default the Chinese font-family. I have dont have the chance to set different classes inside this content. Exactly that's my goal, to set a different class to all a-zA-Z characters via JavaScript or jQuery.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.